# JavaScript - Can you detect wether an event was triggered by the user or the app?

Tags: javascript, events, video

I know that this is possible with for mouse events using the MouseEvent constructor.

For example, with the MouseEvent constructor, you can simulate mouse clicks easily. With this approach, I can add additional fields to my "fake" mouse event such as

```
var event = new MouseEvent(type, mouseEventInit)'
event.fake = true
```

that allows me to detect in the listener wether this event was triggered by the user or the app.

I would like to do something similar with a html video when it is played/paused/seeked. The video can either be controlled by my app (calling `video.play()`, `video.pause()` or setting `video.currentTime = x`) or the user (using the video controls normally) at any given time. When the event listeners I added are fired I do not have a way to know who or what was the source (the user or my app).

So basically, **I don't** want to listen to events triggered by my app but **I do** want to listen to user actions (the user clicked on the play button or seeked in the video by clicking somewhere on the progress bar).

My current approach is to remove the listeners and add them back afterwards like so:

```
video.removeEventListener('play', playListener)
video.play()
// I have to wait until the video actually plays
setTimeout(function() {
  video.addEventListener('play', playListener)
}, 100)
```

It works fine, but when I do this for seeking, it's harder to select a good time for `settimeout` because of video buffering (it seems like the `seeked` event is triggered after the video finished buffering). So I'm exploring different methods.

I know about the CustomEvent() constructor, but I doubt I could use this to actually play or seek. I need to create an event that will trigger the appropriate actions (play, pause or seek). Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Any other ideas I could detect events triggered by my app and/or the user?

Comment: Not clear, here, what you are trying to achieve? What is issue with using `CustomEvent`?

Comment: I still want to fire the `play`/`pause`/`seeked` events when I'm controlling the video within the app. Can I mimic these events using `CustomEvent`?

Comment: Still not sure what requirement is? You can attach and dispatch custom events at elements. What do you mean by "listen to the user actions"?

Comment: Are you trying to call `play` event handler when user action clicks play at `controls`?

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate  what you have tried? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can set a `Boolean` flag to reflect app or user action.

Comment: Mhmm. Mhmm. When I cannot see the obvious like this, it means it's time for me to stop coding. Thank you for your help kind one. Can you write it as an answer so I can give it a green check mark?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a `Boolean` to object passed to event handler to determine if event was dispatched in response to user action or application action.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var div = button.nextElementSibling;

var app = {
  config: "def",
  userAction: "abc",
  setApp: function setApp(duration) {
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
      button.dispatchEvent(appEvent)
    }, duration || 3500);
  },
  timeout: null
}

// dispatch `app` event
app.setApp(0);

function handleEvent(event) {
  // check `event.detail.app` object `Boolean` value
  if (event.detail.app) {
    div.textContent = app.config;
  } else {
    div.textContent = app.userAction;
    // dispatch `app` event in 3500ms
    app.setApp();
  }
}

button.onclick = handleEvent;

// set plain object having `Boolean` value at `event.detail` `{app:true}`
var appEvent = new CustomEvent("click", {
  detail: {
    app: true
  }
});
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<div></div>
```